# Add pipeline stage in the arguments of another pipeline - MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, pipeline, nosql-aggregation

Is it possible to add a pipeline to the arguments of another pipeline in mongodb?

An example of the current result that I am getting:
[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ykTcgCnj4FI)

Is it possible to project the emp table to only name and email field before adding it to the lookup pipeline as an argument?
The result that I want:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("610bce417b0c4008346547bc"),
    "employees": [
      {
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "name": "xyz"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Chicago",
    "number": 10
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  What you seek is the pipeline version of `$lookup`:

```js
db.dept.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "emp",
           let: { did: "$_id" },
           pipeline: [
               {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$did" ]} }},
               {$project: {
                   _id:false,
                   email:true,
                   name:true
           }}
       ],
       as: "employees"
   }}
]);
```

which will yield:

```js
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "Chicago",
    "number" : 10,
    "employees" : [
        {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "email" : "xyz@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```